# Open a Win Form but keep it deactivated while another Form opens

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple WinForm app. For a user to use the app, however, they must login. What I'm trying to do is:

1) open the main form,

2) deactivate it,

3) show the login form,

4) reactivate the main form once the login form is exited and authentication has completed successfully.

I'm looking for some skeleton code just for handling the Win Forms behavior.

Comment: Once your main form is shown just load the login form Modal from the main form, it will block interaction with the main form.

Comment: @Orn After working on this further, I think I understand your comment now. Did you mean to ShowDialog (or some other modal) from the "Shown" event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "Shown" form event, use `ShowDialog()` to make it modal to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough outline

```
protected void MainForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();

    if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
         // proceed with normal flow
    }
    else 
    {
         // let user retry logging in or exit application.
    }
}
```

and in LoginForm, set `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK` if login was successful; otherwise use `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel`

Comment: I'm new to Win Forms, so there might be something I'm missing in making sure this Activated event is triggered/detected. I've tried inserting the code in my MainForm cs. The login form never pops up.

Comment: @Festus did you try setting a breakpoint in your Activated event to see if it ever gets there?

Comment: It's not hitting Activated at all.

Comment: @Festus here's the easiest way to hook up `Activated` is to select the MainForm in Form Editor and select properties. Switch to Events and double click on `Activated`. The form editor will wire up `Activated` to a handler for you and you can place the code in that handler.

Comment: As it turns out, using the Activated event triggers the method everytime anything happens. Attempting to ShowDialog in the Load event prevents the MainForm from loading first. The event to aim for was 'Shown' which triggers the first time a form is shown. I then added the event handler to the .Designer.cs for shown and it works like magic.